# OWASP CSRF Issue For JS Files (required token is missing from the request)

Tags: javascript, csrf, owasp

I have an issue with OWASP CSRF. I implement OWASP CSRF to our java web site.
CSRF works fine for JSP files, but not for js.

We have included js files to our application home page(index.jsp) using script tag with src attribute like below.

```
<script src="plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

When we implement OWASP CSRF to our application, we encounter the following error while loading JS files : error:required token is missing from the request

I know we could make all js files to become unprotected with csrf properties file. But we want to be sure, if is there any way to set OWASP CSRF token to js files.

Could you suggest a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing this? GET requests are usually not protected against CSRF.

Comment: Thank you Teemu. We are trying to force this, because our security team tested the page with some tools. And they asked this after the test results. May be I can say them "GET requests are usually not protected against CSRF." as you mentioned. But I have to make sure of that.

Comment: The [OWASP CSRF Cheat-Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) assumes HEAD, GET and OPTION requests are safe (that is: no back-end state changes). Also, AFAIK you can't fork the headers of the GET requests made by a browser when it loads scripts to the tags on the page. So I think it's not even possible to do what you want. Maybe this could be done with a service, but even that should rely on some forgeable headers, I can't find this a worth of all the work. Maybe you're in need of authorization instead?.

Comment: Teemu thank you again, these info is very valuable for me. 
But I have another question now; Is it possible to make a referer control for those js files? I asked this because one of the security pentest result is about referer header change of js. Or also can we say similar things for the referer control like before you mentioned about GET requests?

Comment: Probably it is possible, though you can easily forge the Referer header (using proxy or by sending the request directly from a server). Like I said, it's not worth of all the work to try to hide public resources. If you have something you really need to hide, place it outside of the public document root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Teemu. We solved the issue with additional development.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).